# Groovy - Joining two SQL Select results

Tags: mysql, arrays, list, join, groovy

before even explaining anything, I'll just leave you here what I have (a summary tho):

rowsTable1 (it has the result of a SELECT, it contains X rows with Y columns)

rowsTable2 (it has the result of a SELECT, it contains W rows with Z columns)

What I want, is to insert into each rowsTable1 row, a row from rowsTable2, but I need to filter rowsTable2 by an ID I have in rowsTable1.

For example, in rowsTable1, I have an element called superID and another called ultraID, and rowsTable2 has those elements too, and that's what I need to merge both rows.

My question is, how can I filter rowsTable2 to only get the row I want?

```
rowsTable1.eachWithIndex{ rowT1, i ->
    rowT1 << rowT2.firstRow([rowT1.superID],[rowT1.ultraID])
}
```

Like this?

Thanks!

Comment: You may have to create a composite row, as the resulting Row objects returned from the query may be immutable (final).  Perhaps "def ret = rowsTable1.collect { rowT1 -> new HashMap().addAll( rowT1 ).addAll( rowsTable2.find { it.superID == rowT1.superID && it.ultraID == rowT1.ultraID } ) }"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to use "collect" to create a composite map, as I don't think you'll be allowed to change the list of Rows that came back from the SQL query.

Here's a sample that should do what you want:

```
// if we start with this data (pretend it's what came back from your queries)
def rowsTable1 = [ [superID :1, ultraID :2, c:'a1b2'], [superID :1, ultraID :3, c:'a1b3'] ]
def rowsTable2 = [ [superID :1, ultraID :3, d:'a1b3extra'], [superID :3, ultraID :4, d:'unfound'], [superID :1, ultraID :2, d:'a1b2extra']]

// Now, join the rows to a List of new "row-like" Maps when superID and ultraID are equal.
def ret = rowsTable1.collect { T1row -> 
    [:] << T1row << rowsTable2.find { it.superID == T1row.superID  && it.ultraID  == T1row.ultraID } 
}
```

ret should now be a List of Maps, each of which is the "merged" Row data for all the unique combinations of superID and ultraID in rowsTable1.  Note that any data in rowsTable2 that doesn't have a superID/ultraID combo that exists in rowsTable1 is ignored, and that all combos that exist in rowsTable1 should exist in rowsTable2.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Also, I found that join{} could be used too, but your solution suits me better.